# Error reading file in working directory python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file in python. This is the code I am using:

```
# test script
import csv
import json
import os


def loadKeys(key_file):
    json_keys=open(key_file).read()
    data = json.loads(json_keys)
    return data["api_key"],data["api_secret"],data["token"],data["token_secret"]

KEY_FILE = 'keys.json'
print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret = loadKeys(KEY_FILE)
```

However it returns the following error

```
->print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
['.DS_Store', 'keys.json', 'script.py', 'test.py']
->api_key, api_secret, token, token_secret = loadKeys(KEY_FILE)
IOError: (2, 'No such file or directory', 'keys.json')
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `KEY_FILE` has no path, so it defaults to looking in the current directory.  You've listed the file in another directory, which is the result of:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Use `os.path.join`:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
loadKeys(os.path.join(path,KEY_FILE))
```